# Split Date() in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

What's the best way to split Date() into Day, Month, and Year?

I've tried:

```
CurrDate = Date()
TodaysDate = split(CurrDate,"/")
```

Which gives me an array:

```
TodaysDate(0) = 7
TodaysDate(1) = 22
TodaysDate(2) = 2014
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eeeket2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [Day](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyhfe92k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [Year](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhzx965c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) functions to get the values you need.

```
CurrentMonth = Month(Date())
CurrentDay = Day(Date())
CurrentYear = Year(Date())
```